# Binomial distribution find n from formula

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have a formula and values  P(X ≤ 20) = 0.95, k=20, p= 0.18
$$
\mathbb{P}[X=k] = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
$$
and I need find $n$. Anybody know how ?

Comment: $P(X=k)$ won't be anywhere near that high for any $n$. Did you mean e.g. $P(X\le20)$?

Comment: Yes probably P(X≤20).